# slow sql query execution

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have following rather simple query

```
select count(*) from tbl t1, tbl t2
```

For some reason it takes tens of seconds to execute this command. I wonder why it happens? It seems that it builds Cartesian product of that tables (table has about 270k rows), but amount of rows is obvious without building product.

Some clarifications would be helpful.

Comment: The cartesian product is known to be slow because it returns all of the data.

Comment: Despite the 5 down votes, I think this is a good question.  Oracle does not always use every table in a query, it's not unreasonable to expect Oracle would apply that same optimization here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume that the optimizer is not built to optimize for cartesian products (especially not for large tables as you mention). In your case it probably build the complete result set and counts it.

Rather than fight it, just count the table once

```
select count(*) from tbl
```

and build the product yourself.

(I assume that you have a more useful case in mind than the rather senseless self-join you posted :-), please add some more info on what you want to achieve.)

Comment: +1 I agree that the optimizer doesn't seem to work well with cross joins.  My guess is that since 99% of all cross joins are application bugs, Oracle doesn't put a lot of effort into optimizing it.  Which is unfortunate, because some times when I really need to use a cross join the optimizer completely fails.

Answer (score 2):

If just want to know the Cartesian product why not calculate it yourself?

```
SELECT Power(COUNT(*), 2) AS product 
FROM   tbl t1;
```

Comment: @jon thanks. In fact I checked in a online tool which showed its correct. Seems it just checked the syntax. Not validated it.